# How to filter data from DTO and save to array list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, collections

How to filter data from DTO and save to array list.

From my JPA Reposttiory query

```
List<MyModel> myList = myRepository.findByPlaceContaining(name);
```

I am getting this result.

```
[
{name:”david”, roll : 101, id: 101-david, dept: “cs”, type:”admin”, someExtra : “etc”},
{name:”david”, roll : 102, id: 102-david, dept: “ECE”, type:”admin”, someExtra : “etc”},
]
```

Now in response I just want to send. (Desired Result) :

**Name,roll,dept and id.**

```
[
    {name:”david”, roll : 101, id: 101-david, dept: “cs”},
    {name:”david”, roll : 102, id: 102-david, dept: “ECE”},
]
```

Here is catch. Dept is coming from different table.

My Model is Loke this :

```
public MyModel(String name, String roll, UUID id,  Dept dept, String admin, String someExtra, Geometry myModel) {
    this.name = name;
    this.roll= roll;
    this.id = id;
    this.dept = dept;
    this.admin = admin;
    this. someExtra = someExtra;
    this. myModel = myModel
}
```

And this myDto

myDTO :

```
public MyDto(String id, String name, String roll, String admin, String someExtra) {
    Id = salesRegionId;
    this.name = name;
    this.roll = roll;
    this.admin = admin;
    this.someExtra = someExtra;
}
```

Now here I am trying converting to get my Desired result.

```
private List<MyDto> convertMethod(List<MyModel> myList) {
    List<MyDto> myModel = myList.stream().map(this::convertToMyDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<MyDto> myTempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(MyDto myDto: myModel) {
        MyDto myTempDTO = new MyDto(myDto.getName(), myDto.getId(),myDto.getRoll(), myDto.getCreatorId(), myDto.getCreatorName());
        myTempList.add(myTempDTO);
    }
    return myTempList;
}
```

Can you please help me to here if I can do this by using any other Data Structure where I can directly covert and add into array list to return.

Comment: is it possible to join the two tables eg: https://thorben-janssen.com/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear from your question what exactly do you need to filter? There's no conditional logic in your code at all.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko In my `convertMethod ` I want to take only those value which I need from `myList` argument and add to myTempList arraylist.

Comment: @sjy I am getting the result after joining table in `myList`, I just want to modify to send my desired result.

Comment: @David *"take only those value which I need from myList"* - based on what criteria? In the `convertMethod()` you're **ignoring** `myModel` list obtained from the stream (why?), and returning a deep copy of `myList` received as an argument without any filtering. Your intention isn't clear for me.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko My Intention is that, I am getting these data from Repository `{name:”david”, roll : 101, id: 101-david, dept: “cs”, type:”admin”, someExtra : “etc”},` to return response to ccontroller I want only this `{name:”david”, roll : 101, id: 101-david, dept: “cs”, type:},`.     Now i was just learning and using stream to achive that, little new here so confused.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko thanks for time. I have update my code, When I am using for loop for each index of `myDto` I have this `{name:”david”, roll : 101, id: 101-david, dept: “cs”, type:”admin”, someExtra : “etc”}` only this i want is when I am adding to `myTempList ` I want only filter data which is : `{name:”david”, roll : 101, id: 101-david, dept: “cs”, type:}`, I just creating a `new myDto` but that is not giving correct result. it is giving reslut as per DTO>

Comment: @David Can you please post the desired result next to the current one.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I ahve updated. I may use any other java collection or Data Structure to active this.  (Not sure).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247912/discussion-between-alexander-ivanchenko-and-david).

Comment: *"I unterstand I need to created another DTO to achive that"* - you don't need to define a different class for that.